# Update screen when passing param with my drawer on the same route React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i have a problem, like i said on the title, i have a list of collections in my drawer and i want to pass their id to go to the screen "Articles" and have a list with a new fetch. It works with my first choice without issue. But if i want to use another collection, the screen is not refresh by itself. The new list will display only if i refresh it manually. Here's some code to help you :
// My Drawer content where i map all my files :

```
  {file.map((f, i) =>
            <DrawerItem
              key={f.id}
              icon={({ color, size }) => (
                <Icon
                  name='description'
                  size={size}
                  color={color}
                />
              )}
              label={f.name}
              onPress={() => {  navigation.navigate('Articles', { screen : 'Articles', params : {id :  f.id}})}}
            />
          )
```

// My Articles screen where i'm fetching the list with the Id of my collection :

```
async componentDidMount() {
let token =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('jeton')

this.setState({
  token : token
})
const { id } = this.state.route.params;

const url = `http://10.1.0.248/api/1/collections/${id}/types`
  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer" + this.state.token,
    },
  }).then(response => response.json()).then((types) => {

    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
      files: types
    }) 
  })

}
```

and here's my Navigator Component :

```
const StackArticles = createStackNavigator();
const StackListe = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const ArticlesStack = () => (
 <StackArticles.Navigator headerMode='none' initialRouteName="Articles">
  <StackArticles.Screen name='Articles' component={ListArticles} />
  <StackArticles.Screen name='Pdf' component={PdfView} />
  </StackArticles.Navigator>
);

const ListeStack = () => (
  <StackListe.Navigator headerMode='none' initialRouteName="Liste">
    <StackListe.Screen name='Liste' component={Liste} />
    <StackListe.Screen name='Pdf' component={PdfView} />
 </StackListe.Navigator>
);



const DrawerNavigator = (props) => (
 <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}   initialRouteName="Home">
<Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    swipeEnabled: false, // to disable swipe gesture for a specific page(s)
  }} />

<Drawer.Screen name='Articles' component={ArticlesStack}
  options={{
    swipeEnabled: false, // to disable swipe gesture for a specific page(s)
  }} />

<Drawer.Screen name='Liste' component={ListeStack}
  options={{
    swipeEnabled: false,
  }} />

<Drawer.Screen name='Settings' component={Settings}
  options={{
    swipeEnabled: false,
  }} />

 </Drawer.Navigator>
)
```

I made some search but i found some answer with deprecated methods like `ComponentWillReceiveProps`
or with some old version of `react-navigation` (i'm using 5). So if someone has an idea it could be really great. Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved this issue with `ComponentDidUpdate` and a condition `if(this.props.route.params !== prevProps.route.params)` and my `fetch` method. i wanted to avoid that but i didn't find any other solution..